# How can I programmatically upload video( using video url of external sites ..eg.youtube) into Asset Library in SharePoint 2013 using obejct model?

Tags: object-model, video

My question is:

How can I programmatically upload video( using video url of external sites ..eg.youtube) into Asset Library in SharePoint 2013 using obejct model?

Please advise.

Regards
Sunny

Comment: So you want to steal someones content?

Comment: Tried using object model code.